# Display semicolon separated string as list items

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have the following JSON array

```
var json = [
 {  
    'albumTitle':'Title',
    'leader':'Leader',
    'trackList':'track1;track2;track3;track4'
 },
etc...
}]
```

I'm iterating through the array and displaying on page with a standard for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    $("#albums").append(`
     <div>
         <p>`+json[i].albumTitle+` by ` +json[I].leader+`</p>

         <h1>Track List</h1>
         <p>`+json[i].trackList+`</p>
     </div>
     `);
```

How can I display `json[i].trackList` as separate list items? Like:

```
<ol>
    <li>Track 1</li>
    <li>Track 2</li>
    <li>Track 3</li>
</ol>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you would want a nested loop that looks similar to the one you have.

Comment: If you do `json[i].trackList.split(/;/i)`, it will create an array. You can loop through that array to seperate each track into a `li` tag.

Comment: But that doesn't *solve* the OP's problem, does it @MarcoBonelli?

Comment: $(function(){
  var json = [
 {  
    'albumTitle':'Title',
    'leader':'Leader',
    'trackList':'track1;track2;track3;track4'
 }
];

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  var tracks = json[i].trackList.split(';');
  var res = tracks.map(a => `<li>${a}<\/li>`).join('');
  console.log(res);
    $("#albums").append(`
     <div>
         <p>`+json[i].albumTitle+` by ` +json[i].leader+`</p>
         <h1>Track List</h1>
         </div>
        <ol>
       ${res}
        </ol>
     `);
}
});